# Server Crash – Memory Issue? Emergency php-fpm Restart Not Working

Tags: memory, amazon-ec2, crash, php

After months of trials and tribulations, I was able to successful get my website operating relatively efficient on an Amazon instance.  However, unfortunately, on occasion the server crashes, at what appears to be random times.  These crashes have occurred after the web server has been up for several days and typically happen during non-peak traffic hours.

The web server is currently on a c3.xlarge instance which contains 7.5 GB of Ram and I have pm.max_children set at 60 and memory_limit for php is set 128M.  When running the top command through Linux, the average RES for the apache processes are in the 80M range.  I assume that the issue revolves around memory usage, but I am not positive.  The memory appears to gradually increase.  When the server crashes, I can easily bring it back to life by running php-fpm restart, but this is clearly not a long term solution.

When looking through the error logs I find:

```
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: child 10404 stopped for tracing
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: about to trace 10404
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 10404: Input/output error (5)
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: finished trace of 10404
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: child 10405 stopped for tracing
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: about to trace 10405
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 10405: Input/output error (5)
[16-May-2014 12:35:26] NOTICE: finished trace of 10405
```

As well as…

```
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 9424 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 126.568819 seconds from start
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 10537 started
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 10122 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 59.041135 seconds from start
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 10538 started
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 8881 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 175.978531 seconds from start
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 10539 started
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 7099 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 310.218902 seconds from start
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 10540 started
 [16-May-2014 12:35:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 6282 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 380.138489 seconds from start
```

While I would ideally find the source of the problem and correct the problem, the emergency variables sounded like a valid solution, but they don’t appear to automatically reset php-fpm.

```
emergency_restart_threshold = 3
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
```

Any ideas on the memory issue? Or why these emergency variables are not automatically restarting php-fpm when the child exits with signal 15? Is it possible to restart php-fpm on a daily timer?

Comment: With php-fpm, php runs as a process separate from apache. In this case, you should not be loading mod_php. You do appear to have something locking up php threads though. This may provide some insight: http://indude.com/php-fpm-error-solved-failed-to-ptrace-peekdata-pid-input-output-448

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Mod_php is disabled and when running phpinfo() the server API is FPM/FastCGI. I have slowlog enabled, but it doesn't appear to provide anything useful. Any other ideas?